# Can Windows 11 run Bitlocker on a Mirrored partition?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker, mirroring

I have a new laptop for work, I own it but need to store business files on it. I've been told to set it up a certain way to comply.

1. Work drive must be mirrored in case of disk failure, and
2. Work drive must be encrypted (Bitlocker or similar)

I have 2x 1TB M2 SSD devices. I don't want to mirror the OS or personal files, installed programs, etc as it'd waste a lot of space. I understand RAID is not a backup so let's not go there, not my rules, we'll do that separately.

So ideally I would have: OS (600GB on device 1), Work (2x ~400GB mirrored, one from each device), Personal Data (600GB on device 2).

The rules are based around desktop devices where you can easily fit multiple disks so partitioning them isn't required, but we aren't sure if it'll work for the laptop with only 2 disks. Have tried searching but many results are very old or not useful.

On my current desktop which has Windows 10 Pro, I have mirrored a disk partition to test this but it will not allow Bitlocker. The disks with the mirrored partition are flagged as Dynamic and online it says this doesn't work.

On the laptop I have Windows 11 Home which does not offer mirroring, the context menu item is missing. So before paying money to upgrade I wanted to check if what I want is possible now under Windows 11? Or is there another method?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic disks are not supported by bitlocker - correct.
You would need to use the new way of mirroring, called "storage spaces" (in control panel, or via start menu), which supports Bitlocker.

Wait, storage spaces would need 2 extra drives (extra meaning non-OS), you only have one. Ok, so that would NOT work.

Say, does your laptop support RAID? If it supports RAID1, you can setup a mirror through it and Bitlocker will support it. However, that would mean, the whole drive is mirrored, again something you don't like, but you can't help it.

Else, there's only syncing (free sync software), that runs every hour or so and keeps those drives mirrored - BL has no problem with that :-)

Comment: Yeah, laptop only has 2 NVME slots, so it seems that the OS software is quite limited in this area for that setup. Storage spaces says it needs whole disks not partitions as you note. Not sure about hardware RAID - it's an Intel NUC X15 and I don't think it has it. I may need to push for an alternate solution, a proper backup system should mitigate risks more than RAID.

Comment: Which x15? There are 3. 2 of them support RAID, needs to be activated in the bios: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/intel-nuc/laptop-kit/KC57_PROD_SPEC.pdf so there is your mirror option which is supported by Bitlocker! For backup, use an external drive to sync with from time to time.

Comment: BKC71EBFU6000 so I think that's a yes. Still has the issue of losing half the capacity, which is what I was hoping to avoid. Maybe it's just impossible apart from the timed sync like you say which will probably spike performance more.

Comment: Sync will not be hard on performance as tools do a good job there. And yes, that model has RAID.